# How do I count number of clicks of links in for-loop in Django template tag?

Tags: javascript, html, django

So I have a Django application, where I upload one article per day (to be more precise, I provide title and subtitle of the article as well as its link, so the user can click the link to see the whole article). I have made this using for-loop in template tag, as shown below.

```
...
{% for item in articles %}
<div class="row">
    <a href="{{item.url}}" class="all-articles" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <div class="col">
        <span class="title">{{item.title}}</span><br>
        <span class="subtitle"> | {{item.subtitle}}</span>
    </div>  
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Now I'd like to see the number of clicks of each article. But I have no idea on how to make it possible.  Any idea? 
Thank you very much in advance. :)

Comment: You can increase article views by one every time user reloads it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, you need to write a view which will redirect you to the url, and in the mean time, count the click. For example(partially copy pasted from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)):

You can use `RedirectView` for redirection:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleCounterRedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = False
    query_string = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        article.update_counter()
        return article.url
```

Then, add it to `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from article.views import ArticleCounterRedirectView, ArticleDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('counter/<int:pk>/', ArticleCounterRedirectView.as_view(), name='article-counter'),
]
```

Finally, update the template with following code:

```
<a href="{% url 'article-counter' item.pk %}" class="all-articles" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
```

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, wouldn't the url override the existing url, which is the link to my article?

Comment: no, just in the list page of articles the old urls will not exist, instead they will pass through the redirect view to end up in your articles.

Comment: Oh I think I forgot to mention one important thing. I actually have my articles in Notion, so I'm trying to outlink to the Notion page. Sorry for the confusion. :(

Comment: It is all the same, but links on the list page will not show notion urls but will end up there at the end.